Copying Word content into excel with formatting and Autosave
I am trying to piece together a number of individual codes / functions, into either A (Preferably) a button that sits natively in the Word Ribbon for all our users, or B(if A is too difficult) a button in a master template document, which all users will have to use each time they want to run this automation.
Currently our quotations are exported from a third party cloud system in Word format, but we have to present them in Excel. The current process is as follows -

Open a new Excel document,
format the first 4 column widths
Open the word document from Downloads folder,
CTRL A CTRL C to copy entire word document
CTRL V into cell A1 of excel sheet
Click Unwrap text then Wrap text to format text in individual rows
Manually save as the same filename as the original Word document

With practice this can be done in a minute or so, but the number of times each day our users are doing this and the discrepancies in formatting and filenames with various users, is making this tedious now.
Using power automate, I have recorded a couple of functions to try and break this down, but coming a little unstuck now and perhaps I am coming at it from the wrong angle altogether?
This works really well in formatting the columns widths -
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    let selectedSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
    // Set width of column(s) at range A:A on selectedSheet to 400
    selectedSheet.getRange("A:A").getFormat().setColumnWidth(400);
    // Set width of column(s) at range B:D on selectedSheet to 125
    selectedSheet.getRange("B:D").getFormat().setColumnWidth(125);
}

and this works well with copying over the required data from the word document -
Sub ImportSectHWord()
  Dim WordApp As Object
  Dim objDoc As Object
  Dim wdFileName As Variant
 
  wdFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Word Documents, *.doc*")
  If wdFileName = False Then Exit Sub
  Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
  Set objDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(wdFileName)
     
  WordApp.Selection.WholeStory
  WordApp.Selection.Copy
 
  ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Select
  ActiveSheet.Paste
  objDoc.Close False
  WordApp.Quit
 
  Set WordApp = Nothing
  Set objDoc = Nothing
End Sub

This is script was recorded when unwrapping / wrapping the copied over source data -
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    let selectedSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
    selectedSheet.getRange().getFormat().setWrapText(true);
    selectedSheet.getRange().getFormat().setIndentLevel(0);
    selectedSheet.getRange().getFormat().setWrapText(false);
    selectedSheet.getRange().getFormat().setIndentLevel(0);
    selectedSheet.getRange("A1").getFormat().setIndentLevel(0);
    selectedSheet.getRange("A1").getFormat().setWrapText(true);
    selectedSheet.getRange("A1").getFormat().setIndentLevel(0);

However the above does require us to have the excel / target document open to run the macro, find and select the correct word / source document via the open pop up box etc., hence why it would be good to have a native button in Word, so when the source document is opened from the download folder, we click the native button and the following functions run -

Source content is copied
New excel workbook is opened
Column formatting takes place
Source content is pasted into A1
Unwrap / wrap formatting entire sheet
Save as pop up, auto populated with source filename (less the .docx)
User then selects destination folder and saves.


Cross-posted at: https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/copying-whole-word-document-into-excel-formatting-columns-and-cells.1263892/
For cross-posting etiquette, please read: http://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?184
